# Is it possible to use two seperate for a Joomla website?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, joomla

Is it possible to use two different templates for a Joomla website?

We want to display a different template for all registered visitors in our Joomla website. We would like to have a "control panel feel" for all of the registered users and would like to use one of the admin templates on wrapbootstrap, let's call it template #2.

Our site is currently using a Joomshaper template, let's call it template #1. We are very happy with the look and feel of template #1. We would like non-registered visitors to use template #1. Once a visitor logs into the site and becomes "registered", we would like to use template #2.

Example:

- Use template #1 for non-registered visitors
- Use template #2 for Registered visitors

Does anybody know how to implement this type of architecture?

Thank you

Comment: It's really unclear what you are talking about. Installing a template is done using the extension installer but I'm sensing that isn't what you mean. ALso all of Joomla uses Bootstrap so it's not something special to say "a bootstrap template."  Also templates do not actually normally control what you see, that is done with access control such as checking if a user is logged in. Templates control the css and things like location of modules.  You need to explain a bit more of what you actually are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks Elin, I understand your points of clarity (or confusion) so I reworded the whole question in hopes it makes more sense. You're correct in your sense, installing the template was not the question sorry I took you down that path. And using the term "bootstrap" steered the read in the wrong direction too. Thank you for sharing your frustration in the way I worded the question. It allowed me to clarify what we're trying to do. I hope it makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this, one using a single template and one using two separate templates. In a single template you can conditionally introduce elements (layout, css etc) and so on based on testing whether the user is logged in. That can work but also get pretty complex in terms of readability.

The other thing would be to use two separate template styles for the same or different templates.  The default template style is set in the template manager and what you want to do is use different template styles for the two groups. There are some extensions that will implement this for you but you can also see this in the site administrator where users can opt to have the accessible template rather than the standard Isis template. (It is set with the "backend template style" field). You can see the code for this is `libraries\cms\application\administrator.php` `getTemplate()` method. So one possibility would be to override that method with your own for the front end since the site application doesn't have this option. If you read the code you will see that one option is that you can change the template by adding a `template=` segment to the request. You will probably get good advice about this

There are some extensions that will help do this for example http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/style-a-design/templating/template-assigner (I've never tried it).